# Database recovery pending on external drive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have database with mdf and ldf file residing on external drive. There was a long powercut and the database restarted. Now the database has gone for recovery pending. The database is around 600 gb.

I have tried the following commands

```
ALTER DATABASE ‘DATBASE NAME’ SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

ALTER DATABASE ‘DATBASE NAME’ SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

but i am getting the following error

> Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 4 Unable to open the physical file
>   "G:\SQL_DATA\TEST_NEW.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is
>   denied.)". File activation failure. The physical file name
>   "G:\SQL_DATA\TEST_NEW_log.ldf" may be incorrect. Msg 5181, Level 16,
>   State 5, Line 4 Could not restart database "TEST_NEW". Reverting to
>   the previous status. Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 ALTER
>   DATABASE statement failed.

I have tried all options.

Do any body has a working solution. Please share it will save my day.

Comment: Hi, do the files "G:\SQL_DATA\TEST_NEW.mdf" &  "G:\SQL_DATA\TEST_NEW_log.ldf" exist? Does the sql server service account have sufficient rights on this folder?

Comment: Yes both the .mdf and .ldf exists on the path. There is no rights issue.

Comment: I tried the DBCC TRACESTATUS it give me the following message. " DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator."

Comment: The G:\ Is an external drive right? What kind of drive is it?

Comment: Its a hard drive size around 1 TB.

Comment: If you don't care about the log file, you could try attaching it without the log: `CREATE DATABASE [dbname] ON
(filename ='G:\SQL_DATA\TEST_NEW.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG` I think that the account executing the command also needs sufficient rights on the folder.

Comment: Unable to dettach the database. it is giving me error.   

Alter failed for Database 'TEST_NEW'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)


Unable to open the physical file "G:\SQL_DATA\TEST_NEW.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Could not restart database "TEST_NEW". Reverting to the previous status.
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
File activation failure. The physical file name "G:\SQL_DATA\TEST_NEW_log.ldf" may be incorrect. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

Comment: Attaching it as a new database name also not possible? Which error?

Comment: Please check whether these two files(mdf and ldf) has read.write access to the user which is used to start MSSQL service.

Comment: The error message is clear. The service accout don't have permissions on those file. One thing you can do is to stop your SQL server and copy (not move) the files to an appropriate place and then attach the files. (Or fix the permission issue, if that is the right thing to do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your support, I figured out the issue. Our Admin skipped one user. domain\Users was missing from the folders permission. I know it is a silly mistake. But because of this I got to learn more.

I added permission to the folder by adding the domain\Users, and the error disappeared.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, make sure the SQL service account has permissions on the files.
Here is a quick snippet to help you do that:

```
-- From SQL:
-- get full path for master
SELECT SUBSTRING(physical_name, 1,
CHARINDEX(N'master.mdf',
LOWER(physical_name)) - 1) DataFileLocation
FROM master.sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = 1 AND FILE_ID = 1

-- get the service accounts
SELECT servicename, service_account FROM sys.dm_server_services
```

```
# From Powershell (run as admin) and replace with values you got from the previous step 

# replace with master db path
$masterDBLocation = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL1\MSSQL\DATA\'

# replace with SQL service account
$serviceAccount = 'DOMAIN\svc_DatabaseEngine'

$mdf = 'G:\SQL_DATA\TEST_NEW.mdf'
$ldf = 'G:\SQL_DATA\TEST_NEW_log.ldf'

$Acl = Get-Acl $masterDBLocation
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($serviceAccount, "FullControl", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)

Set-Acl -Path $mdf -AclObject $Acl
Set-Acl -Path $ldf -AclObject $Acl
```